# How do I insert an external SVG into an SVG drawn with d3?

Tags: svg, d3.js

How do I insert an external SVG into an SVG drawn with d3? I am not trying to draw on an external SVG, I'm trying to insert it into one that I generate with d3.

I've done the following:

```
var root = d3.select('#svg')
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

d3.xml("foo.svg", 'image/svg+xml', function(xml) {
  root.append(xml.documentElement);
});
```

but I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function d3.js:559"

Comment: I don't want to draw on an externally loaded svg. I want to insert an externally loaded SVG into a d3 generated svg.

Comment: That's what the code in that question does.

Comment: The code in that question draws a circle on brussels.svg, which is loaded externally. I want the contents of brussels.svg inserted into a circle generated on the webpage.

Comment: So you want to use the SVG as a background image? https://gist.github.com/vitch/3226952

Comment: No, I've generated an svg chessboard using d3. But I have external svg files of each of the pieces that I'd like to place on the board.

Comment: ah, this did it: .append('svg:image')
 .attr('xlink:href', '/images/tile-us.png'); thanks!

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as to what you were actually looking for, but never mind if your problem is solved :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53910/discussion-between-jshou-and-lars-kotthoff)